# Getting an error Request entity is too large

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am redirecting from one page to another by using this command.

```
Response.Redirect("~/Viewer/ViewerTest.aspx");
```

Sometimes, I am redirected to this page and sometimes, I am not. Actually very rarely, i am redirected to this page. If I am not redirected, I get an error

> The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large

I tried to play around with this command by putting actual project name instead of tilde, but again sometimes it worked sometimes, it does not.

```
Response.Redirect("~/Viewer/ViewerTest.aspx");
```

Along with the above command, I am passing a query string with it, the query string value is very small, it is `Id=<the calculated value>` which is integer value not more than 100.

Also, this error is not coming on development computer, only on my production computer. My dev computer works fine. The production computer has Windows Server 2008 and my dev computer has XP. The Internet Explorer version is 7.0

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it does and sometimes doesn't?

Request entity body becomes large

1. When you upload a large file from your web page
2. When you submit a web page of large content

Setting `uploadReadAheadSize` in applicationHost.config file on IIS7.5 would resolve your issue in both cases. You may modify this value directly in applicationhost.config or use this command:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webserver/serverruntime/uploadreadaheadsize: 1048576 /commit:apphost
```